Onesignal push notifications not popping up in Android device - Flutter
I noticed that when I go to permissions -> notifications , there's a Miscellaneous property that is turned off. The popup only appears if I turn it on.

Is there a way that when I accept notification permission it gets turned on? Or, is there a config in OneSignal's side so that the notification always pops up?
